# Is it possible to write reliable application for Android and iOS with Qt?

Tags: android, ios, qt

What's the state of Qt for mobile application development?

Is it still buggy (2 or 3 years ago I remember it had bugs for using camera, font sizes, etc)? If yes what are the bugs?

What's size of a Qt application bundle for an application mostly using Media components? (please go to details about it, can the developer chose to not include libraries in the bundle so that if the user already has the libraries app uses those Qt libraries?)

How much memory does it consume comparing to Android apps created with Android SDK?

If everything is alright, why there aren't lots of Qt applications out there for Android and iOS? Do Google and Apple somehow discourage using Qt?

Please share anything you have about Android and iOS application development with Qt (all pros and cons).

Comment: ahh.... this really sucks. I also want to know how far Qt has come for IOS/Android. Yes, sure there are some bad questions, but this is not one of them. There is some opinion based questions here, but I would say the OP is mostly after factual information: "are there still bugs?" "what are the pros and cons?" @Sassan, I am sure you can tweak those words to ask for facts and not opinions : )  .... I am sure I will cop some grief from the "put-it-on-hold/close-it police" for this comment :p  but sometimes its very hard to ask a purely fact based question and some question just need to be asked

Comment: @code_fodder Ok, I'll edit it and will try to ask about facts.